# How do I create a page with a sidebar similar to the WordPress customization page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking to make a page with settings in a sidebar overlay type frame on the far left hand side for settings very similar to the Wordpress customization page found [here](http://demo.opensourcecms.com/wordpress/wp-admin/customize.php) (username: admin password: demo123).

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could achieve this, or have any links to tutorials?
I couldnt find any in my search.

Thanks,
John

Comment: Do you want to have a sidebar only (the menu as a kind of accordion) like they have or the functionality to manipulate the right side's content too?

Comment: manipulating the right side content is the idea, but I think I'm able to do that with some javascript stuff that I already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by using **jQuery UI**: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Just add your own custom style and give your sidebar `position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0` to let it look like wordpress sidebar...

If you want to manipulate the right side's content you may want to use **jQuery** to manipulate `HTML`, `CSS` or whatever when changing the settings in your sidebar.

Comment: Thanks, it had completely skipped my mind that you can fix to the left like that.